# JS: Why don't the switch statement cases `case 2` and `case day == 2` print out the same result?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I understand the following code.

```
var day = 2;
switch (day) {
    case 1:
        document.write("Monday");
        break;
    case 2:
        document.write("Tuesday!!");
        break;
    case 3:
        document.write("Wednesday");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("Another day");
}
```

It prints out "Tuesday!!".

However, why doesn't the following work? I though it should have printed the same answer, but it keeps printing "Another Day"!?

```
var day = 2;
switch (day) {
    case day == 1:
        document.write("Monday");
        break;
    case day == 2:
        document.write("Tuesday!!");
        break;
    case day == 3:
        document.write("Wednesday");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("Another day");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because switch case statements compare the supplied arguments automatically. So on calling `day == 3`, it's actually running `day == 3 == 3` which isn't a correct syntax.

Hope it clear your doubts.

Comment: Aaah... that makes sense! Thank you.

Comment: @Grateful Glad to hear it clear your doubts. If it resolves your concern, Can you upvote and accept the answer to close this thread?

Comment: Yes, of course! But please give me a bit of time to digest all the other answers. Much appreciated.

Comment: Actually it's `(day == 3) === 3` (with strict equality), and actually this is valid syntax - it just doesn't evaluate to true.

Comment: (day == 3) === 3 will be the same as (Boolean) === 3, right?

Answer (score 1):

A case in a switch statement tries to match with the switch condition directly. So your snippet:

```
var day = 2;
switch (day) {
    case day == 1:
        document.write("Monday");
        break;
    case day == 2:
        document.write("Tuesday!!");
        break;
    case day == 3:
        document.write("Wednesday");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("Another day");
}
```

Is actually equivalent to:

```
var day = 2;
switch (day) {
    case false:
        document.write("Monday");
        break;
    case true:
        document.write("Tuesday!!");
        break;
    case false:
        document.write("Wednesday");
        break;
    default:
        document.write("Another day");
}
```

And since `day` is not equal to either `true` or `false` (since it is, in fact, `2`), the switch falls through to its default case.

You can see that cases use strict equality from [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) (emphasis mine):

> A switch statement first evaluates its expression. It then looks for
>   the first case clause whose expression evaluates to the same value as
>   the result of the input expression **(using strict comparison, ===)** and
>   transfers control to that clause, executing the associated statements.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me. Because 2 is a truthy value as well! And so far as I know `true == 2` should be true. So according to this, I think it still should have worked.

Comment: @Grateful `true !== 2`. `switch` uses strict equality.

Comment: Aaah! That makes more sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @Bergi is correct, but I added a link to the docs so there can be no doubt. ;)